# Dplyr::summarise dropping variables

Tags: r, dplyr

I am using both dplyr's "mutate" and "summarise" function after grouping my dataframe by one of my variables "ID". the problem I am facing is that the only variables that are being kept are my grouping variable (ID), and the two variables I am creating using the summarise function. I am losing the variable "Category" that is being created using the mutate function.

Why is this happening and how I can keep all my variables?

```
RMI.2 <- RMI.1 %>%
  dplyr::group_by(`ID`) %>%
  dplyr::mutate("Category" = ifelse(`Repl - A Check` >= 1, "A",
                               if_else(`Repl -B Check` >= 1, "B",
                                       if_else(`Repl - A Check` >= 1 &  `Repl -B Check` >= 1, "B", NULL)))) %>%
  dplyr::summarise("total time out" = sum(`Time of RMI`, na.rm = TRUE), "Number of RMI's" = n())
```

I tried using the .drop but that did not work:

```
dplyr::group_by(`ID`, .drop=FALSE)
```

Comment: This is expected. The purpose of `summarize` is to aggregate data down to one row per group. Any column that you don't specify how to aggregate is dropped. If you want to keep all rows, use `mutate` instead. If you do want one row per group (one row per ID, since that's what you group by), and you want to keep the `Category` column, you have to tell `summarize` what to do with multiple values. For example, if ID 1 has categories A A B do you want to keep the first? The last? The most frequent? (what about ties?) Something else?

Comment: the difference between `summarise` and `mutate` is that `summarise` returns a single value and `mutate` returns a vector of the same length as the inputs. 
The reason `Category` is dropped is that probably there are different `Categories` within each `ID` group. 
You can either use `group_by(ID, Category)` before summarizing or decide a rule how to summarize different `Category` values into a single one.

Comment: @Cettt A quibble with *"The reason Category is dropped is that probably there are different Categories within each ID group"* - it doesn't matter whether or not there *are* different categories within each ID group, or how "probable" that is. `summarize` **will drop all variables** that are not part of the group definition or in an aggregate function - doesn't matter if they are all the same within the group, or even if each group is only a single row. Without aggregation instructions, they will be dropped.

Comment: Thanks. Not sure why I was set on using summarise as I can just use mutate and perform my summary functions and create two other variables. thanks for the clarification on how summarise is used though.

Comment: @Gregor I know. I just wanted to illustrate why in the general case (i.e non unique Category) a trivial summary is not possible and hence has to be included

Comment: Yeah, I figure you know, but I've seen too often newbies assume that columns that *don't* vary by group (but aren't explicitly included in `group_by`) can be included without an aggregate function. "There's only one value, why doesn't it work?" I think it's an important early lesson that dplyr won't (and shouldn't!) "assume" a trivial aggregate, even when it is possible.